# Sort Descriptor not working in ios

Tags: ios, sorting, nssortdescriptor

i used the Sort Descriptor to Sort the NSMutableArray By one & multiple Values,First i tried by to sort By Price,it sort in some other Order here is my code help me,
My 
i create the Dictionary by below code and added to the NSMutableArray

```
    for(int i=0;i<[priceArray count];i++)
    {
        cellDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [cellDict setObject:nameArray[i] forKey:@"Name"];
        [cellDict setObject:splPriceArray[i] forKey:@"Percentage"];
        [cellDict setObject:priceArray[i] forKey:@"Price"];
        [resultArray addObject:cellDict];
    }
// To Sort in Ascending Order
    NSSortDescriptor *sort =[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Price" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort, nil];
    NSArray *sortedArray=[resultArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

    NSLog(@"Result %@ Sorted arr %@",resultArray, sortedArray);
```

And Output  is:

```
 Result (
        {
        Name = "Black Eyed Peas";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 80;
    },
        {
        Name = "Black Gram";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 56;
    },
        {
        Name = "Channa White";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = "Double Beans";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 95;
    },
        {
        Name = "Gram Dall";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = "Green Moong Dal";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 150;
    },
        {
        Name = "Ground Nut";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 140;
    },
        {
        Name = "Moong Dal";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 75;
    },
        {
        Name = "Orid Dal";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = "Toor Dal";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 150;
    }
) Sorted arr (
        {
        Name = "Channa White";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = "Gram Dall";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = "Orid Dal";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = "Ground Nut";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 140;
    },
        {
        Name = "Green Moong Dal";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 150;
    },
        {
        Name = "Toor Dal";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 150;
    },
        {
        Name = "Black Gram";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 56;
    },
        {
        Name = "Moong Dal";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 75;
    },
        {
        Name = "Black Eyed Peas";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 80;
    },
        {
        Name = "Double Beans";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 95;
    }
)
```

Here The Sorted Array Sorting in some other Order I want to sort this in Ascending order by price.

Comment: Are the price values `NSNumber`s? For my dummy data your code actually works, I cannot reproduce your issue...

Comment: We need a bit more info: what are the objects you are trying to sort? How is the "Price" property defined? It looks to me like the numbers in Price are being sorted by their string value, which leads me to believe Price is an NSString property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what your test data looks like - but the following snippet works as expected

```
NSArray *priceArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@(74),@(100),@(100),@(130), nil];
    NSArray *nameArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Yva",@"Hallo", @"Adam", @"Xavier", nil];

NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for(int i=0;i<[priceArray count];i++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *cellDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [cellDict setObject:nameArray[i] forKey:@"Name"];
    [cellDict setObject:priceArray[i] forKey:@"Percentage"];
    [cellDict setObject:priceArray[i] forKey:@"Price"];
    [resultArray addObject:cellDict];
}
// Sort by Name
//NSSortDescriptor *sort =[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Price" ascending:YES];

// Sort by Name
NSSortDescriptor *sort =[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort, nil];
NSArray *sortedArray=[resultArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

NSLog(@"Result %@ Sorted arr %@",resultArray, sortedArray);
```

Result:

```
2015-07-11 12:54:54.358 ret[10480:162783] Result (
        {
        Name = Yva;
        Percentage = 74;
        Price = 74;
    },
        {
        Name = Hallo;
        Percentage = 100;
        Price = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = Adam;
        Percentage = 100;
        Price = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = Xavier;
        Percentage = 130;
        Price = 130;
    }
) Sorted arr (
        {
        Name = Adam;
        Percentage = 100;
        Price = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = Hallo;
        Percentage = 100;
        Price = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = Xavier;
        Percentage = 130;
        Price = 130;
    },
        {
        Name = Yva;
        Percentage = 74;
        Price = 74;
    }
)
```

Comment: Yes it's worked for me, i changed like this only as you said [cellDict setObject:@([priceArray[i] intValue]) forKey:@"Price"]; Thank you...@seeya

Comment: but it not worked for Name My descriptor is     NSSortDescriptor *sort =
    [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name"
                                ascending:YES
                                 selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

Comment: Hi seeya i need help i tried the Filter in same by  NSArray *resultAr = [[cellDict allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Price == %@)", @"150"]];
    NSLog(@"RESULT %@",resultAr); it getting error reason: '[<__NSCFNumber 0x146db5e0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Price.

Comment: cellDict is : {
    Name = "Toor Dal";
    Percentage = 0;
    Price = 150;
}

Comment: use NSPredicate *sort = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Price == %d", 100];  - Pleas read https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html first